# Check if Window is already exist , then make the window as active else open

Tags: sikuli

I am new to sikuli  , Is there a way to find whether the Microsoft Outlook is already opened ? If its opened make it as a active window else open Outlook .

Below is the code which i tried  , Some times the Maximize() will work correctly. Otherwise it will open outlook even if it already exists

```
OutlookOpen()

def OutlookOpen():
if exists("1424161703182.png"):
    Maximize()
else:
    openO()

def Maximize():
switchApp("Microsoft Outlook")
wait(1) 
type(" ", KEY_ALT)
type("x")
print("Maximized")

def openO():
OpenApp(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\outlook.exe')
wait(2)
print("opened")
```

Comment: switchApp() is on it's way out, and App.focus() is the thing to use going forward

Comment: Is Outlooked previously minimized to the task bar? Sikuli can have trouble telling between an app that is open but minimized (i.e. to the task bar), and an app which is open and visible--in both cases the switchApp() method returns true, but when it's minimized, sikuli can't manipulate it until you restore it (make it visible).

Comment: My observation : If outlook Is the main window then scripts works properly , if outlook is not the main window and if its minimized then it will goto else part (i.e will open a outlook). Is there any workaround ??

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is look if outlook exists (grab something unique, pictures are most easy). If is doesn't exist look if outlook exists on the minimized bar (picture is mostly a little different, and sikuli is sensitive).

For example:

```
Image_TB_Open = ("image1")
Image_TB_Minimized = ("image2")

class ThunderBird():
    def __init__(self):
        self.TBird()
    def TBird(self):
        if exists(Image_TB_Open):
            print('ThunderBird is open!')
        elif exists(Image_TB_Minimized):
            print('ThunderBird is open but minimized!')
        else:
            print('ThunderBird is closed!')

# Run class 
ThunderBird()
```

Edit:

Okey, I made a far more simple solution. 
Might as well share it here. 
I made a definition to do the work for me.

```
# vcProgram = Program name. 
def programActive(self, vcProgram):
    self.vcProgram = vcProgram
    searchResult = App.focus(vcProgram)
    if (vcProgram in str(searchResult)):
        return 'True'
    else:
        return 'False'
```

To call this definition I use:

```
fActive = self.programActive('Firefox')
```

If `fActive` is `True` then the program is already open.