# Checking if an application is already open with Sikuli

Tags: javascript, python, jython, sikuli

I'm creating a script in Sikuli for automated testing but have come across what seems a basic issue that I cannot seem to find a workaround for.

The problem I have is that I am trying to use 2 different apps for the script I am working on. To be exact, if the applications are already open, the program fails to focus on them and tries to run onto the next couple of lines

I have read through the limited documentation Sikuli has online and seen many other's similar issues but I cannot apply any of that to fix this issue.

Code:

```
appone = App("C:\Program Files (x86)\appone.exe")
apptwo = App("C:\Program Files (x86)\apptwo.exe")

if(appone.isRunning(3)):
    appone.focus()
else:
    appone.open()

if(apptwo.isRunning(3)):
    #do nothing#
else:
    apptwo.open()

wait(5)

click("image.png")
```

I have tried using image recognition to check the window's taskbar to see if the app is running but that throws out other errors as well.

Appone is the main application running which I am using Sikuli for, and apptwo is a helper application that needs to be running for appone to do what I need it to do.

What is the best way to solve this issue?

EDIT: I found a great solution that I tweaked to fit my situation from the answer of this thread: [Check if Window is already exist , then make the window as active else open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559997/check-if-window-is-already-exist-then-make-the-window-as-active-else-open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the issue could be when you are using the app .exe location to identify if the app is running maybe. Could you try checking if the same is working if you use the window title to check if the app isRunning instead of .exe path. Please find an example below:

```
if(App("Untitled - Notepad").isRunning() == True):
  print "App found!"
  App("Untitled - Notepad").focus()
else:
  print "App not found!"
  App.open("Notepad.exe").focus()
```

Also, i got this to work in Sikuli 1.1.4 in case if you are wondering.

Comment: I am using 1.1.3 because my work hasn't approved updating yet. This was very helpful though. My issue now is that the version tag is in the title as well and with updates coming out frequently, it will be too much of a hassle to keep going back and replacing the strings in this script. Do you know if this could possibly work with only part of a window title?

Comment: Continued to play around with Sikuli some more, it seems that if you use the process name of the application, it will work just like using the window title's but in a more robust fashion.

Comment: That's good news... Nice to hear you got your issue solved. :)